# How to compute percentage of total based on Counts of 1 field and filtered by another field

Tags: sql, sql-server

Data and Desired Result:

[image]

I have the above data, i would like to compute the percentage and show the corresponding counts of the records.  The CountKey is a concatenation of 3 fields, i only want to count it when it is unique by LastName,  I then would like to find out the percentage of total for each different Status type by last name.  The CountKeyTotal is the total count of unique CountKeys for Smith, CountKey is the Total unique Countkeys by LastName by Status

I am fairly new to SQL and have only been able to get either totals in whole (as an example using the data provided, Smith 40 3 12 25%

any help would be appreciated

Comment: i  have the MS SQL server mgmt studio and also SQL Report Services to work with

Answer (score 0):

You can use a group by and a dinamic temp table for total

```
  select 
    a.name, a.status
 ,  count(a.countKey) as CountKEy
 , c2 as CountKeyTotal
 , (a.count(*) / b.c1) *100 as percentage 
 from my_table as a 
 inner join( select name, count(*) as c1 , count(countKey)  c2 from  my_table
             group by name) b  on a.name = b.name
 group by a.name
```